# Can you choose contacts to be on your iMessage account?

Tags: ipod-touch, messages

I am concerned about it. If I get started on iMessage, will it come up with all the contacts I have now or can I select them?

Answer (score 1):

iMessage doesn't have the concept of a contact list like you might have had on Windows Live Messenger, AIM or Skype.

It operates like traditional SMS. If someone has your number or email address, they can send you a message.